# How to create a PDF view of multi page Dash App?

Tags: python, pdf, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a multi-tab / page Dash Application with the following file structure:

```
index.py
app.py
Tab 
-- Tab1.py
-- Tab2.py
---- SubTab1.py
---- SubTab2.py
```

Here's the app layout from `index.py`:

```
app.layout = html.Div([

    # header
    html.Div([

        html.Div(
            ,style={"float":"right","width":"170px","height":"100px","margin-top":"-14px"})
        ],
        className="row header"
    ),

    # body
    #html.Div(className='background')

    # tabs
    html.Div([

        dcc.Tabs(

            id="tabs",
            vertical=True,
            className="mb-3",
        
            children=[

                 dcc.Tab(label="Tab1", value="tab1_tab",
                         children=[dcc.Tabs(id="subtabs", 
                            children=[dcc.Tab(label='subtab1', value='subtab1'),
                                      dcc.Tab(label='subtab2', value='subtab2')      
                            ],
                         
                    )
                 ]),
                 dcc.Tab(label="Deal", value="deal_tab")

            ],
            
        )

        ],

        className="row tabs_div"

    ),

        # Tab content
        html.Div(id="tab_content", style={"margin": "-11% 8.9%", "float":"left"}),

])
```

Now, I'd like to export and save a PDF view of contents of `subtab1` and `subtab2` with persist state. How would I go about doing this? Seems like you can do this for a single page app, however, I am not so sure about multi-page app.